# Trying to find out when system running Solaris 9 was last updated

Tags: unix, solaris

I am looking to find out the last time a Solaris 9 box we are running was updated with OS patches, new software installed, etc. I need some way to prove when the last changes to the system were. I am running command line only and am not particularly familiar with Unix-like systems.

Comment: Do you suspect that this was an automated update, or a manual update?

Comment: I don't suspect that there was any update, but I need to prove it for an audit. If there was an update it would have been manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this for Solaris 8 http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.solaris/how-to-show-the-last-time-solaris-8-machine/65540

```
ls -lrt /var/sadm/patch
```

Appears to show timestamps from when patch packages were applied. Also used:

```
ls -lrt /var/sadm/install_data/
```

to show timestamp of patch log.